# List of all available google play library APIs

Tags: google-play-services

I'm trying to find a list of all available google play libraries (eg. AUTH or GAMES), and can't find it in their docs

Where can I find it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this google docs [Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/) which lists Google APIs for Android:

```
DEVELOP

  -Analytics
  -Cloud Messaging
  -Authentication
  -Realtime Database
  -Storage

  -Hosting
  -Remote Config
  -Test Lab
  -Sign in with Google
  -Maps
  -Places

  GROW

  -Notifications
  -App Indexing
  -Dynamic Links
  -Invites
  -Adwords
  -App Install Ads

  EARN

  -Admob
```